# WPF Manipulation | Multitouch

Tags: c#, wpf, multi-touch

Осуществил манипуляцию с помощью ManipulationDelta, а именно манипуляцию над Image, хотел бы понять, как узнать координаты обеих картинок и как-то сравнить их чтоли, нужно переместить верхнюю картинку в нижнюю так сказать но не прям туда где стоит нижняя картинка ибо пока прицелишься..
либо создать какую-то область чтоб если картинка входила в эту область ну и делать какие-то действия, тестирую это для программы викторины(вопросики всякие и тд).
Гуглил насчет всего этого ничего не нашел, форумов про мультитач очень мало :с
p.s. в WPF новичек :)

[image]
[image]
В итоге будет что-то вроде этого, незнаю как узнать правильный ответ на вопрос..

Comment: а теперь еще раз, но внятно

Comment: не совсем понятно, что вы хотите получить